# Jetpack Media3 Library with Compose: Service not in sync with ViewModel

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-media3

I'm using Jetpack Media3 library alongside Jetpack Compose for playing audio. I have created a PlaybackService to manage media playback and I am using a ViewModel RadioViewModel to manage the UI logic in a composable function RadioView.

Here's a brief breakdown of my code:
PlaybackService:

```
class PlaybackService : MediaSessionService() {
    private var mediaSession: MediaSession? = null

    // Create your Player and MediaSession in the onCreate lifecycle event
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        val player = ExoPlayer.Builder(this).build()
        mediaSession = MediaSession.Builder(this, player).build()
    }

    // This example always accepts the connection request
    override fun onGetSession(
        controllerInfo: MediaSession.ControllerInfo
    ): MediaSession? = mediaSession

    // Remember to release the player and media session in onDestroy
    override fun onDestroy() {
        mediaSession?.run {
            player.release()
            release()
            mediaSession = null
        }
        super.onDestroy()
    }
}
```

RadioView:

```
@Composable
fun RadioView(url: Uri, viewModel: RadioViewModel = viewModel()) {
    val isPlaying by viewModel.isPlaying.observeAsState(false)
    val playbackState by viewModel.playbackState.observeAsState(0)
    
    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        viewModel.setUri(url)
    }

    Text(
            text = "Play Audio From URL",
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
            fontSize = 24.sp,
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
            color = Color.Black,
            modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)
        )
        Button(
            onClick = { viewModel.togglePlay() },
            modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)
        ) {
            Text(
                text = if (isPlaying) "Stop $playbackState" else "Play $playbackState",
                color = Color.White,
                fontSize = 18.sp
            )
        }
}
```

RadioViewModel:

```
class RadioViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
    private val _isPlaying = MutableLiveData(false)
    val isPlaying: LiveData<Boolean> = _isPlaying
    private val playerReady = MutableStateFlow(false)
    private var _player: MediaController? = null
    private val _playbackState = MutableLiveData(0)
    val playbackState: LiveData<Int> = _playbackState

    init {
        val sessionToken =
            SessionToken(application, ComponentName(application, PlaybackService::class.java))
        val controllerFuture = MediaController.Builder(application, sessionToken).buildAsync()
        controllerFuture.addListener(
            {
                _player = controllerFuture.get()
                playerReady.value = true
            },
            MoreExecutors.directExecutor()
        )
    }

    fun setUri(uri: Uri) = viewModelScope.launch {
        playerReady.first { it } // Wait until the player is ready
        val mediaItem = MediaItem.fromUri(uri)
        _player?.let { player ->
            player.setMediaItem(mediaItem)
            player.prepare()
        }
        play()
    }

    fun togglePlay() = if (_isPlaying.value == true) pause() else play()

    private fun play() {
        _isPlaying.value = true
        _player?.play()
    }

    private fun pause() {
        _isPlaying.value = false
        _player?.pause()
    }

    override fun onCleared() {
        super.onCleared()
        _player?.release()
        val intent = Intent(getApplication(), PlaybackService::class.java)
        getApplication<Application>().stopService(intent)
    }
}
```

My problem is that when I pause the player from the notification (outside the app) and then return to the app, the UI still indicates that the player is playing, which is out of sync with the actual playback status.

How can I ensure that the service and ViewModel stay in sync in this scenario? Any advice or insights would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to observe the playback state in your view model.
Here is an example: 
https://github.com/android/uamp/blob/main/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/uamp/viewmodels/NowPlayingFragmentViewModel.kt#L98